# slf4j logger log level not inheriting correctly

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I have a class where I've created 3 different slf4j loggers:

```
package x.y.z;

public class MyClass {
    private static final Logger logger1 = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    private static final Logger logger2 = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class + "-a);
    private static final Logger logger3 = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class + "-b);

    public void myMethod() {
         // some code that logs to all loggers at debug level
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that even with x.y.z.MyClass configured at debug level, MyClass-a and MyClass-b loggers are not logging at debug level, they instead log at the root level configured (info in my case). Even specifying a specific logger for the -a and -b, as shown below, does not work. They will not log at debug level until I change the root to debug. Really stumped with this, any ideas?

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
   ....
  </appender>

  <logger name="x.y.z.MyClass" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="x.y.z.MyClass-a" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="x.y.z.MyClass-b" level="DEBUG" />

  <root>
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why should "x.y.z.MyClass-a" inherit settings from "x.y.z.MyClass"? It is not more similar than "x.y.z.OtherClass".

Comment: @Henry because doesn't inheritance of logger levels work by finding the closest logger substring. Even trying setting debug for name="x.y.z" did not work.

Comment: Substring is too broad, see logback docu: "A logger is said to be an ancestor of another logger if its name followed by a dot is a prefix of the descendant logger name.", thus only something like "x.y.z.MyClass.a" should inherit the config. This does not answer your second point though.

Comment: @Henry ok, I didn't know the . was important. But yeah it still  doesn't explain why config for x.y.z had no effect or why he config which matches the exact name also has no effect

Answer (score 1):

Since you've mentioned wrong class name in log configuration.

`<logger name="x.y.z.MyClass" level="DEBUG" />` it must be 
 `<logger name="x.y.z.myClass" level="DEBUG" />`

Better change your class specification to `public class MyClass { }`

Edit:

Try by specifying package name alone `<logger name="x.y.z" level="DEBUG"/>` which equivalent log4j property is `log4j.logger.x.y.z=DEBUG`

Comment: sorry, this was just a mistake in my example in the question, the actual code did not have such a problem. I've edited it now.